# replace ceramic capcacitor with electrolytic one

Tags: arduino, capacitor, circuits

I need help, that i have a lack of ceramic capacitor value variety   in my country.

I need 47μF (microfarad) and 2.2μF (microfarad) ceramic capacitor and i can't get these values.

So the question is, can i put a number of many small capacitor in parallel to compensate that absence of the large capacitor?! Would that affect the performance of the entire circuit?

I'm using the 47μF capacitor to filter an external power supply to the circuit. And the 2.2μF one is to filter a DC motor signal.

And what is the effect of using a capacitor with a higher voltage than i already using in my circuit. For example: the recommended capacitor to use in the circuit is (47μF 16V), what is the effect if i used (47μF 50V) or maybe higher voltage.

Or can i totally change the ceramic capacitors with electrolytic ones? should i consider the same values?

Comment: Explain where in your circuit these capacitors are found.  Post a schematic.

Comment: @NickAlexeev https://ibb.co/jJbXoL

Answer (score 0):

Those values seem excessively large for ceramic capacitors, particularly given the DC application as power supply decoupling. I would make sure that the design actually calls for ceramics.

Generally you would have a large value electrolytic (which also has considerable series resistance and inductance) to take care of relatively slow changes in current demands, in parallel with a medium size ceramic to take care of the fast transients and to filter EMI.

In the motor application, it is possible to get a reverse polarity, so an electrolytic could fail. Also an electrolytic would not work well for EMI.

But to answer your question, yes putting the capacitors in parallel will work, it is also very likely to give you a capacitor with much better characteristics than an equivalent electrolytic. Just make sure to keep the distance between the capacitors short.

The voltage specification of a capacitor is related to the breakdown voltage of the dielectric and the capacitor lifetime. Using a higher voltage capacitor considerably reduces the likelihood that it will fail.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for these recommendations.

So, i will make these parallel set of ceramic capacitors for the motor, as you recommended not to use an electrolytic capacitor instead.

Can i use an electrolytic capacitor for the power supply purpose instead of the ceramic one? Should i use the same value?

Comment: 2.2μF definitely isn't unreasonable for an MLCC. 47μF is pretty big though.

Comment: For the power supply it is common to use an electrolytic in parallel with a much smaller ceramic. But that really depends on the circuit being powered.

Comment: Here is a link to the circuit https://ibb.co/jJbXoL 
C4 is the meant power supply capacitor

Comment: @SalmanMohamed all those capacitors can be electrolytic. It is a rather power-inefficient design as the motor is being driven with mostly DC.

Comment: @EdgarBrown What values should i use?

Comment: @SalmanMohamed You indicated having the values in your question. I can’t answer that without more information on the specifics of the design.

Comment: @edgarBrown I mean, should i put the same values?
As i will replace to electrolytic ones

Comment: @SalmanMohamed yes. Of course. But if you have access to ceramics of the same value those would still be preferable (better overall characteristics).

Comment: I'll try to use ceramic ones as much as possible.
Thank you, sir. @edgarBrown